# Markers in android google maps json

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I have a hicking app, that gets a array of markers from my database and plots them on my map, afterward it draws a polyline connecting all the markers. What i want to do is , to draw the polyline connecting the markers, but instead of showing 10 or 20 or 100 markers, to only SHOW 2, the marker that starts and the one that ends.

Would appreciate any help.
Below is the function that i use to draw the polylines.

```
private void createPolylinesFromLatLng(ArrayList<LatLng> polylist){
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
    for (int z = 0; z < polylist.size(); z++) {
        LatLng point = polylist.get(z);
        options.add(point);
        totalDistanceInMeters = SphericalUtil.computeLength(polylist);
        test=String.format("%.2f",totalDistanceInMeters);


    }
```

and this is how i retrieve my markers into a array

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jo = array.getJSONObject(i);

                            Double lat = Double.parseDouble(jo.getString("lat"));
                            Double lng = Double.parseDouble(jo.getString("lon"));
                            polyline = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jo.getString("lat")),
                                    Double.parseDouble(jo.getString("lon")));

                            polylist.add(polyline);
                          //  location = new LatLng(lat,lng);
                            location=polyline;
                              MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                            options.position(location);
                            mMap.addMarker(options);
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would to just surround your code where you add the `Marker` with a `if` statement like this:

```
if(i == 0 || i == (array.length() - 1)){
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
    options.position(location);
    mMap.addMarker(options);
}
```

That way only the first location and the last location are added.